# jQuery Pass value from textarea to a specific td in a specific tr

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to pass a textarea value, from a dialog window, back to its original td location.

Here is what the tbody looks like:

```
<tbody class="facttbody">
    <tr class="factrow">
         <td>
            <input type="text" class="facttext" value="Replace this value" />
         </td>
```

Here is what the replace button from the dialog window looks like:

```
buttons: {
    "Replace": function (){
        var dialogtxt = $(".factlargetextarea").val();

        $(".factdata > tbody > tr:eq($(".facttext").index(this)) > td:nth-child(5)).html(dialogtxt);
        $(this).dialog("close");
```

This kind of works in that the textarea value is returned to that td, but it removes the input tag from the td as well.  I just tried this too:

```
$(".factdata > tbody > tr:eq($(".facttext").index(this)) > td > input:nth-child(4)).html(dialogtxt);
```

This didn't work either.  Any suggestions?  Thanks...

Comment: You are concatenating strings incorrectly and in some cases missing quotes alltogether.

Comment: Yeah I know, I have a variable = $(".facttext").index(this), I just didnt put it in there.

Answer (score 0):

It will definately remove that input type inside the **td**, because you used **.html()** there, that is rewriting html for that element.

Instead of that, you can use .[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function this :

```
  $(".factdata > tbody > tr:eq($(".facttext").index(this)) > td:nth-child(5)).append(dialogtxt);
```

It will append the data in that **td**, after input element.

Comment: How about if I wanted to put it in the input element for that td?

Comment: Use $('.facttext').val(dialogtext); it will change the value of input element.

Answer (score 0):

If -

```
$(".factdata > tbody > tr:eq($(".facttext").index(this)) > td:nth-child(5)).html(dialogtxt)
```

is changing the entire contents of 'td' then something like -

```
$(".factdata > tbody > tr:eq($('.facttext').index(this)) > td:nth-child(5)).find("input[type='text']").val(dialogtxt);
```

should change the value of the textbox. The second statement just finds the textbox in the `td` then uses the `val` method to change it's value.

Comment: That did it! I was trying to do some kind of "td > input:nth-child(4)" but I was barking up the wrong tree.  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Excellent! Pleased it worked. I'd appreciate it if you could accept the answer if it has helped. :)